# how can i connect to WIFI network using python 3

Tags: python, wifi

i was trying with this code but it does not work

```
from wireless import Wireless

wire = Wireless()
wire.connect(ssid = "netowrk name" , password = "password")
```

Comment: Can you post the error also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"To connect an interface to a wireless medium you have to set a proper machine context.

Then, use the connector mechanism to attach the interface:

(machine-0) connector Connect sysbus.radio wireless"
That´s from the module documentation, maybe you missed that code
Here is the full doc: https://renode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/networking/wireless.html